# Compacting QDialog when elements are removed

Tags: qt, layout, window-resize, qdialog

I have this `QDialog` with a nested `QGroupBox` that may be removed in the dialogue's constructor (through various `QDialog` methods, like `hide()`, `setVisible()` and `setHidden()`). Unfortunately, when I remove it, the dialog remains the same size. The funny thing about that is that the main `QGroupBox` (the one with the nested `QGroupBox`) shrinks, but the rest of the window does not. Consequently, there are large spaces around the main `QGroupBox`.

I've tried:

- Calling `QDialog::resize()` in the ctor *and* through `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()`, to reduce the height by 30 (the size of the removed `QGroupBox`) but that does nothing.
- Calling `QDialog::adjustSize()` (also in the ctor and through `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()`) but that just increases both dimensions (like crazy big!).
- Changing the `QDialog`'s "Vertical Policy" from "Preferred" (whatever that means) to "Minimum" but that does nothing.

The `QDialog` has a grid layout.

Edit: I noticed that there are these `verticalSpacers` above and below the main `QGroupBox`. Whatever I set their policies and size hints to makes no difference--they still make the whole window really big when I call `adjustSize()`. Removing them makes makes `adjustSize()` get the height right, but the width is still way too big. Removing them and not calling `adjustSize()` then causes the main `QGroupBox` to stay the same size, and not shrink due to the removal of some of its children.

I'm running Qt 4.8 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`QLayout::setSizeConstraint`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlayout.html#sizeConstraint-prop) on the dialog layout to force it to resize automatically depending on its content with either `QLayout::SetFixedSize` or `QLayout::SetMinAndMaxSize` as parameter (the latter lets the user resize the dialog).

With `SetMinAndMaxSize`, you may need to change that property on the main `QGroupBox` layout too, or at least set its vertical layout policy to `Maximum` or `Fixed`.